# Can't connect to Chinook.sqlite database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

For some reason python is throwing the following error when i try to connect to "Chinook.sqlite" database and pulling Albums table from it. Would appreciate all the help in this regard.

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: Albums [SQL: SELECT * FROM Albums] (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Code is below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine= create_engine('sqlite:///Chinook.sqlite')
con= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Albums", engine)    
print(con)
```

Comment: It's telling you what is the error- `No such table`.

Comment: Verify the path of the SQLite database file relative to the current working directory of your Python program.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the directory you are working by writing pwd and running it, then modify it for the path of SQLite database file.It worked for me.
[image]